# Warning Symbol Unsigned Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

In the recent update of java (6.10) http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u10.html[link text](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u10.html) the way that unsigned applets was changed. A warning is now displayed. Is it possible to turn this off without signing your applet?

Answer (score 1):

What would be the point of such a warning if you could disable it programatically?

Comment: You would think there would be an option for a white list so you don't keep getting warned about an applet that you trust that has not been signed

Comment: There's no way to reliably identify an Applet that's not been signed. Therefore you couldn't even create a secure white list (because some bad code could come from the same URL that you whitelisted without you noticing).

Answer (score 1):

No way to disable it.

It is a rubbish update. It breaks standard Window functionality and has caused headaches for all the people working in support for any applets. Stinks of some coders trying to add new gimmicks unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to disable it. Do the following:

1. Open C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin and run policytool.exe.
2. In the Policy Tool window click File -> Open and choose the file java.policy from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security.
3. Click on "CodeBase ALL" and on the button "Edit Policy Entry" afterwards.
4. In the Policy Entry window click "Add Permission".
5. In the Permissions window choose "AWTPermission" from the "Permission:" combo box, and "showWindowWithoutWarningBanner" from the "Target Name:" combo box. Then click "OK".
6. Back in the Policy Entry window click "Done".
7. Back in the Policy Tool window click File -> Save.
8. Restart your browser.
9. Enjoy your warning-free applets :).